# Rails: How can I tell if a record has a child record in any one of its child tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm working in Rails 3 and have a table with multiple child tables, e.g.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
  has_many :items
  has_many :widgets
end

class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

Is there a simple way for me to check to if a given Foo has a child record in one or more of the tables? Basically, is there a better way to do this:

```
if !foo.things.empty? or !foo.items.empty? or !foo.widgets.empty?
  puts "This foo is in use!"
emd
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, I think you're on the right track, but maybe just put that as a method in your Foo model

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def children?
    things.any? || items.any? || widgets.any?
  end
end
```

Then just say, `Foo.first.children?` and get `true` if the Foo instance has any children.

Comment: I'd use `any?`, because `present?` has an unnecessary set of checks for string emptiness, and also unnecessarily checks if `[]` is `nil`. Note: `foo.things` will always return an array, albeit sometimes an empty one.

Comment: @veritas you continue to be wrong - I don't think you're understanding active record collections completely.  They don't eagerly load in all cases.  foo.things will *not* always return an array.  In the case of any? or exists? it will not load the ruby objects.  any? does a count and compares with zero which is slower than exists? which just looks for the id in the database.

Comment: @Swards If `foo.things` does not return an array, you've set up your AR relationships wrong, straight and simple. I encourage you to look at my updated answer.

Comment: You're just not understanding something here, or glancing over my answers, or something. Take a look at my answer, and see that I'm actually quite right.

Comment: @veritas - that's exactly what I'm saying: foo.things does not return an array in some cases (eg when '.exists?' is appended).  You can confirm it for yourself - that may change your answer.  It's very similar to how you can append scopes to a collection.

Comment: @veritas - your posted answer shows how the query made with exists? does not load foo.items (ie. it doesn't do a select *)

Answer (score 6):

This is what `any?` is for.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def children?
    things.any? || items.any? || widgets.any?
  end
end
```

Since this has become a topic of contention, I present to you:

```
> foo = Foo.last
Foo Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "foos"......
> foo.items
Item Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "items".*.......
> foo.items.any?
=> true #OH, WHAT's that? NO SQL CALLS? GEE WILLICKERS
> foo.items.exists?
Item Exists (0.5ms) #Hmmmmmm....
=> true
```

The point here is that under any circumstances, `exists` makes a DB call, where as `any?` will not, if `spaces` is always loaded into memory. Now as I said, many times, the importance is not the efficiency of the DB call (AND YES, the SQL call `exists?` makes is more efficient), but the fact that `any?` won't necessarily make a call to the DB, which is a HUGE advantage. Look for yourself:

```
[20] pry(main)> Benchmark.measure { foo.item.exists? }
  Item Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "items" ...
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc1f28a8638
 @cstime=0.0,
 @cutime=0.0,
 @label="",
 @real=0.002927,
 @stime=0.0,
 @total=0.00999999999999801,
 @utime=0.00999999999999801>
[21] pry(main)> Benchmark.measure { foo.items.any? }
=> #<Benchmark::Tms:0x007fc1f29d1aa0
 @cstime=0.0,
 @cutime=0.0,
 @label="",
 @real=7.6e-05,
 @stime=0.0,
 @total=0.0,
 @utime=0.0>
```

For a more concise timing, look at this:

```
> Benchmark.measure { 1000.times {foo.items.exists?} }.total
=> 2.5299999999999994
> Benchmark.measure { 1000.times {foo.items.any?} }.total
=> 0.0
```

Now as I said, many times, it depends on circumstance -- you could have many circumstances where these items aren't loaded into memory, but many times, they are. Choose which one works best for you depending on how you're calling it.

Comment: The OP is not going to preload the collection, then test for existence.

Comment: Yep, what I've been saying all along.

Comment: Oh nvm, I thought you said `IF the OP is not going to preload...`. OP never specified, it very well could be preloaded depending on the situation. Anything that involves `includes` statements, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This should work for any given model.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def children?
    has_associated_records = self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map { |a| self.send(a.name).any? }
    has_associated_records.include?(true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass Thing Item and Widget.  Or add a polymorphic join table to keep track of it.  Not ideal, I know.

You could at least do this, so it would read a little better.

```
if foo.things.exists? || foo.items.exists? || foo.widgets.exists?
  puts "This foo is in use!"
end
```

'empty?' uses 'exists?' behind the scenes, I believe.

Comment: exists? will select '1', any? will do a select count(*). any? is a slower in my tests.

Comment: Not so fast. If any `things`, `items`, or `widgets` are loaded into memory, `exists?` still performs a query for each of these. `any?` does not. It depends on the use case, but given OP's question, it's likely these models will be loaded into memory and thus `any?` will be more efficient.

Comment: They aren't loaded into memory with exists.

Comment: But the important part is that you'd have to make >=1 calls to the database with `exists?`, whereas with `any?`, you could make potentially 0 calls, and usually much less than `exists` (as I said, depends on the situation). Calls to the database are a lot, lot slower than to memory.

Comment: 'exists?' makes a single sql "select '1'" in mysql and tests to see if any results are found.  'any?' will do a "select count(*)".  They both do one SQL call and any? is slightly slower.  Try it for yourself.

Comment: @Swards It should also be noted that I never said `exists?`'s SQL call was slower, but that under a lot of circumstances, it will be a lot slower because it needs to call all `items` from the DB each time whereas `any?` does not.

Comment: @abram, maybe a bit late, but here are some performance tests: https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2017/03/14/faster-rails-how-to-check-if-a-record-exists.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose all the associations are loaded into memory:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :things
  has_many :items
  has_many :widgets

  def in_use?
    [things, items, widgets].flatten.any?
  end
end
```

**Edit**

I just realized that this is wrong: each association (even if still loaded into memory) will be loaded which isn't good.

```
things.any? || items.any? || widgets.any?
```

is more correct and has been proposed before me.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Marcelo De Polli is the most generalized one posted so far.
This answer is an updated version of it for Rails 5.

The parent class for a model is `ApplicationRecord` in Rails 5 and later, which used to be `ActiveRecord::Base` up to Rails 4 (n.b., the original question is tagged as Rails 3).

For simplicity of the code, use:

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  def children?
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map{ |a| self.send(a.name).any? }.any?
  end
end
```

To pursue more run-time efficiency when a model may have many classes of children, use:

```rb
class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  def children?
    self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.each{ |a| return true if self.send(a.name).any? }
    false
  end
end
```